# Regex Positive Lookahead Still Including Expression in Result

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is my regex expression.

```
'(?<=1\)).*'
```

I am trying to match

> A good strategy is a set of actions that enables a firm to achieve its own internal goals without regard to the external environment.

But it keeps returning with the **1)** which I do not want it to like this.

> 1) A good strategy is a set of actions that enables a firm to achieve its own internal goals without regard to the external environment.

How do I only return the question?

EDIT: Since my bug couldn't be reproduced I am sharing the full code.

```
searchCounter = 1

bookDict = {}

with open ('StratMasterKey.txt', 'rt') as myfile:

for line in myfile:
    question_pattern = re.compile((rf'(?<={searchCounter}\)).*'), re.IGNORECASE)
    if question_pattern.search(line) != None: 

        bookDict[searchCounter] = line 
        searchCounter +=1
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/uCAlAi/1, not repro.

Comment: It works as expected on regex101. https://regex101.com/r/PF5anN/1 Can you share more of your code to help debug the problem?

Comment: Hmm... Must be something else then. I edited to include more of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is fine, and is matching the right thing. The problem is that after you test it for a match, you use the original line instead of the matching portion. Do this instead:

```
searchCounter = 1

bookDict = {}

with open ('StratMasterKey.txt', 'rt') as myfile:

for line in myfile:
    question_pattern = re.compile((rf'(?<={searchCounter}\)).*'), re.IGNORECASE)
    result = question_pattern.search(line)
    if result != None: 

        bookDict[searchCounter] = result[0] 
        searchCounter +=1
```